# The search() method in javascript fail to search for "\\ch" in a string containing it

Tags: javascript, string, search, slash

I am trying to find the position of `\\ch` of a latex code, say `foo\\ch` but the search method of string fail to do it. For example running the following code:

```
console.log('foo\\c'.search('\\c')); // expected 3, really get 3
console.log('foo\\ch'.search('\\ch')); // expected 3, but get -1
```

I suspect the "error" is due to `\ch` form a special character but I have searched over internet and it seem `\ch` is not a special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `search()` with a string as an argument it is converted to a regex (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search))

But `new RegExp('\\ch')` returns `/\ch/` which is the regular expression to match any BackSpace character (`\cX` matches control character `X`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-control)).

To achieve what you want use the `/\\ch/` regex

```
'Foo\\ch'.search(/\\ch/) // returns 3
```